# Change color of signs in SignColumn/Gutter

Tags: colorscheme, plugin-syntastic, color, signs

I have set my sign column background using
`hi SignColumn ctermbg=236` in my colorscheme file. However, it seems that the background colors for where there are signs has not been changed, and is the same as my default background color.

Is there a way of changing the background (and if possible, foreground) colors of signs?

[image: The signcolumn/gutter with mismatched background colors]

Edit: For further clarification I'm using Syntastic to get these signs in my sign column, in case that's relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs (`:help syntastic-error-signs`):

```
Signs are colored using the Error and Todo syntax highlight groups by default
(see |group-name|). If you wish to customize the colors for the signs, you
can use the following groups:
    SyntasticErrorSign - For syntax errors, links to "error" by default
    SyntasticWarningSign - For syntax warnings, links to "todo" by default
    SyntasticStyleErrorSign - For style errors, links to "SyntasticErrorSign"
                              by default
    SyntasticStyleWarningSign - For style warnings, links to
                                "SyntasticWarningSign" by default

Example: >
    highlight SyntasticErrorSign guifg=white guibg=red
<
```

Comment: Setting `Error` and `Todo` in my highlighting worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

*Note: Written before OP added the relatively important detail that the signs are generated by Syntastic. Ergo, a general tossing of things against the wall to see what sticks rather than a quick honing in on the actual solution à la the subsequent, accepted answer. It's fine, though.* :P

It seems you are at least partially aware of how this works but let's lay it out formally...

When you define the sign you specify the *highlighting group* to be used when that sign is displayed. (Run `:hi` to see all of your currently defined groups.)

For example, a sign that will have the same background color (*and* foreground color!) as one's `'colorcolumn'` columns could be defined like this...

```
:sign define mysign text=|> texthl=ColorColumn
```

From there you don't need to do anything special. When you place a sign it should have the expected coloring. So let's check off some boxes. Are you/have you...

- Using a recent version of Vim?
- Making sure the highlight group has set `guibg` if you are using GUI vim or `ctermbg` if you're using terminal vim?
- Defined a sign manually with a "clean" version of vim and known-to-be-working highlight group (check it with `:hi HlGroupName`)?

(By "clean" I mean you can, for example, start vim without any plugins using `vim --noplugin` and/or try it without any vimrc file using `vim -u NONE`.)